# Cannot share WiFi connection with LAN cable

Tags: networking, wireless, sharing

I have two PCs. Both run Ubuntu 18.04. After update to 18.04 laptop cannot share Wireless connection with LAN cable. PCs are connecting(ping command logs there is no package loss) but there is no Internet (Wifi sharing is turned on).